# Update bios from 16.04 LTS?

Tags: upgrade, bios, 16.04

They said this is going to be an option. 
Anyone care to provide the way of updating BIOS?

Using Lenovo Z51-70. Need it to enable hybernate and suspend options, since sudo pm-hibernate or suspend doesn't work.

Comment: Who said that was going to be an option?

Comment: @Zacharee1 canonical ;-)

Comment: fwupd should work in Ubuntu as well
For now, the new tool is still being developed, and it’s also dependent on the Linux Vendor Firmware Service, which is an online resource where hardware makers can upload the new firmware. fwupd is not magic, it still needs to connect to an online repository to download and install the new firmware, which in this case is Linux Vendor Firmware Service or LVFS.



Read more: http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-16-04-lts-might-get-the-option-of-updating-firmware-directly-from-the-os-498626.shtml#ixzz46aA3wqWv

Comment: I updated BIOS on my Lenovo G50-45 2 months ago. Windows was the only possible way to do it. BIOS updates  (and instructions) can be found on Lenovo Support page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The software responsible for this is [fwupd](http://www.fwupd.org/)

> **Introduction**
>
> `fwupd` is a simple daemon to allow session software to update device firmware on your local machine. It's designed for desktops, but this project is also usable on phones, tablets and on headless servers. You can either use a GUI software manager like GNOME Software to view and apply updates, the command-line tool or the system D-Bus interface directly.

The command for it is `fwupdmgr`.  The command it self shows this "usage" (so it IS available on a 16.04 install)

```
Usage:
  fwupdmgr [OPTION...]

  clear-results           Clears the results from the last update
  dump-rom                Dump the ROM checksum
  get-details             Gets details about a firmware file
  get-devices             Get all devices that support firmware updates

  get-results             Gets the results from the last update
  get-updates             Gets the list of updates for connected hardware
  install                 Install a firmware file on this hardware
  install-prepared        Install prepared updates now
  refresh                 Refresh metadata from remote server
  unlock                  Unlocks the device for firmware access
  update                  Updates all firmware to latest versions available
  verify                  Gets the cryptographic hash of the dumped firmware
  verify-update           Update the stored metadata with current ROM contents

Help Options:
  -h, --help            Show help options

Application Options:
  -v, --verbose         Show extra debugging information
  --offline             Perform the installation offline where possible
  --allow-reinstall     Allow re-installing existing firmware versions
  --allow-older         Allow downgrading firmware versions
```

Now for a problem: there is a [devices list](http://www.fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist)  and the official one is short, very short and incomplete.

> **Devices using LVFS for firmware updates**
>
> This list shows all the updates that have been pushed to the stable metadata. This is a very incomplete list as a lot of the devices in the LVFS have not yet been released publicly and the firmware updates are in a secret embargoed state.
>
> This list is automatically generated and will be updated when new firmware is added or devices are released to the public.
>
> **Dell Inc.**

```
XPS 15 9550/Precision 5510 System Update
Edge Gateway 5000/5100 System Update
OptiPlex 7440 AIO System Update
XPS 13 9350 System Update
```

> **Hughski Limited**

```
ColorHugALS
ColorHug
ColorHug2
```

Comment: I'll try to update this when new firmware is added to the page